# "Metalness" using MTLLoader in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

Recently I've started using MTLLoader for my obj meshes in Threejs.

It gets the job done, as it loads the proper textures and such, but the material is too matte for what I want.

What I expect:

[image: I expect these glasses to be metallic, like this]

What I am getting:

[image: I am getting this]

I am not sure how to change the "metalness", "roughness", "secular", etc. properties of this mesh as I used MTLLoader.

I have a suspicion that it may be my lighting that makes it look like its matte in color.

Code for lighting:

```
function setLighting(){
    const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 2, 10);
    light.position.set(0, 10, 0);
    scene.add(light);
    var hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffbb, 0x080820, 2 );
    scene.add( hemiLight );
}
```

The function above is called only once in my code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not sure how to change the "metalness", "roughness", "secular", etc. properties of this mesh as I used MTLLoader.

Please be aware that materials loaded by `MTLLoader` are always instances of `MeshPhongMaterial`. This is no PBR material which means you can't configure properties like `metalness` and `roughness`. I suggest you check out the official documentation page of [MeshPhongMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/MeshPhongMaterial) to understand the available properties.

BTW: `MTLLoader` does not support PBR materials like `MeshStandardMaterial` or `MeshPhysicalMaterial` because unlike glTF the OBJ/MTL standard itself defines no PBR workflow. If possible, I recommend you use glTF instead of OBJ.

Comment: thanks! I will try and use GTLF and see how it works